# How to retrieve sorting status of JQuery Datatables

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom, datatables

I'm pretty new to JQuery Datatables,

I'm attempting to retrieve two information about the Datatable

1. Which column index is currently being sorted (aka selected)
2. Which order it is being sorted (asc or desc)

not sure how I should approach this (use jquery to find the column index or does Datatables have an API that allows me to retrieve this information.

thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you mean by "retrieve", but if you define your `datatable` like this:

```
myDataTable = $('#my-table').dataTable({
              .
              .
              .
              });
```

You have access to its setting via:

```
myDataTable.fnSettings();
```

See also:

1. http://datatables.net/api#fnSettings
2. http://datatables.net/docs/DataTables/1.9.0/DataTable.models.oSettings.html

For example to get an array of columns sorted columns, try:

```
myDataTable.fnSettings().aaSorting;
```

http://datatables.net/docs/DataTables/1.9.0/DataTable.models.oSettings.html#aaSorting

Comment: I used this which basically gets me an array of sorting $("#my_table_id").dataTable().fnSettings().aaSorting;

Answer (score 2):

the method order() returns  an array of arrays containing index and direction sorting .

[take a look at api](https://datatables.net/reference/api/order%28%29)