# jQuery DataTables 1.10: Which column is it sorted on right now?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables-1.10

Using DataTables 1.10,

I have a DataTable with a default sort and the user can resort by some of the other columns.

How do I detect the column by which the table is currently sorted?

---

Some context which may not be relevant to answering the question:  What I'm really trying to do is "export" the table to a non-interactive HTML table.  This DataTable is generated programmatically and then turned into a DataTable, so after some searching for export options it looks like it will be easier to essentially regenerate the original table than to actually export.  But I need the regenerated table to have the rows in the same order as the current sort.

Comment: Does this post help solve what you're trying to do? --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251787/how-to-retrieve-sorting-status-of-jquery-datatables

Comment: @ejhost, not quite; that's basically the same question, but the only answer applies to an older version of the DataTables plugin.  I've edited the question to emphasize the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current sort state `sortInfo` can be retrieved like this:

```js
var apiObject = $("#myPlainTable).DataTable( dtOptions );
// ...
var sortInfo = apiObject.settings().order()
```

More specifically, the column and direction are encoded like this:

```js
var sortCol = sortInfo[0][0]; // counting from left, starting with 0
var sortDir = sortInfo[0][1]; // either "asc" or "desc"
```

**Caveats:**

The `sortInfo` object will have the above format after the user changes the sorting; if you specify the initial sort by setting `dtOptions.order` using a different format, then the `sortInfo` object will have the original value you specified until the user changes the sorting.  (For example, DataTables will accept `[1,'asc']` in addition to the above `[[1,'asc']]`; I didn't test what happens if you pass a value DataTables can't use.)

This describes the default case where you sort by one column only, not using the multi-column sort feature.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using dataTables 1.10.x already, why not use the [**API**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/)? By that it is easy :

```
table.rows().data()
```

returns an array of arrays containing the *current* content of the table, i.e the rows as they are currently sorted. So if you want to export or clone the content of a dataTable to a static table, you can actually do it very simple :

```js
$("#clone").click(function() {
  var cloneTable = '';
  table.rows().data().each(function(row) {
    cloneTable += '<tr><td>' + row.join('</td><td>') + '</td></tr>';
  })
  $('#cloneTable tbody').html(cloneTable);
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/zuxm2e68/**

Answer (score 0):

If sending to the server you check the

```
order[i][column] 
order[i][dir]
```

for column and direction. See [here](http://datatables.net/manual/server-side)

Comment: That link goes to documentation about Server-side processing, but there is no server-side processing going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using 1.10, you can use the following:

```
var table = $('.myTable').dataTable({ /* Your options */ });
var sortArray = table.api().settings().aaSorting; // gives array
```

If you are using API already via `$('.myTable').DataTable({...})`, you can omit the `.api()`.

Comment: api_object.settings().aaSorting is undefined.

Comment: I'd have to get permission, which I won't be able to ask for until Monday.  It basically works as described in my answer; the `settings()` method returns a object with several methods attached, but no other types, and no aaSorting.